# Can We Register Service Worker from Cross-origin

Tags: javascript, https, service-worker, fetch-api, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to Use a CDN network to host my service worker which allow cross-origin CORPs. Then I came To know About fetch API to access cross Origin Resources.
Here Code Which I'm using on my Index.HTML to register service worker

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('https://www.otherdomain.com/sw.js').then(function(registration) {
      // Registration was successful
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
    }, function(err) {
      // registration failed :(
      console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err);
    });
  });
}`
```

How To Use Cross cross-domain Service worker with fetch API

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting the service worker only working trough https anyways would be beneficial not to include this into your html file but rather in another js file.

Here is something that would call you sw.js file. include this into your html or again another js file.

```
var deferredPrompt;

if (!window.Promise) {
  window.Promise = Promise;
}

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('sw.js')
    .then(function () {
      console.log('Service worker registered!');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function(event) {
  console.log('beforeinstallprompt fired');
  event.prompt();
  deferredPrompt = event;
  return false;
});
```

Try **This**

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {

  var url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'; //add your URL here 
  if (event.request.url.indexOf(url) > -1) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
        .then(function (cache) {
          return fetch(event.request)
            .then(function (res) {
              // trimCache(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME, 3);
              cache.put(event.request, res.clone());
              return res;
            });
        })
    );
  } else if (isInArray(event.request.url, STATIC_FILES)) {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
    );
  } else {
    event.respondWith(
      caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response) {
            return response;
          } else {
            return fetch(event.request)
              .then(function (res) {
                return caches.open(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME)
                  .then(function (cache) {
                    // trimCache(CACHE_DYNAMIC_NAME, 3);
                    cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());
                    return res;
                  })
              })
              .then(function (err) {
                return caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
                  .then(function (cache) {
                    if (event.request.headers.get('accept').includes('text/html')) {
                      return cache.match('offline.html');
                    }
                  });
              });
          }
        })
    );
  }
});



self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  console.log('[Service Worker] Installing Service Worker ...', event);
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_STATIC_NAME)
      .then(function (cache) {
        console.log('[Service Worker] Precaching App Shell');
        cache.addAll(STATIC_FILES);
      })
  )
});
```

Comment: here what error I get `DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker: The origin of the provided scriptURL ('https://rawgit.com') does not match the current origin `

Comment: can you add your whole service worker? As I understand You trying to fetch the service worker from somewhere rather then from your local recources? Just need more information.

Comment: This error comes when I use your any of above script.

Comment: did you add the cors headers? Just need more info then couple of lines of code.

Comment: This CDN enabled CORS header for all domain even my manifest.json is hosted on it

Comment: added more stuff in my answer try using fetch event rather then load. delete some of the stuff that you dont need you need to add static cache and dynamic cache as well. Is the issue only with your sw ?

Comment: Above Error Removed but still service worker not installed

Comment: well you dont install it anywhere in your code you just fetch it sofar

Comment: you need to install it activate and then fetch whatever you want to

Comment: Hey! I Can't figure out how to install it can you tell me

Comment: Added more code but to be honest just google it. More likes would be appreciated :D